# How to visualize synfusion charts with in UWP applications using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, uwp, syncfusion

How to visualize synfusion charts with in UWP applications using sqlite ?

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a simple sample using SfChart with SQLite in UWP application and please find the sample from the below link,

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/189153/ze/SfChartWithSqlite_UWP-1685553605

Regards,

Durga S